# What documents are required to apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, paperwork

I am applying for a Schengen visa for a month and my travel dates will be within this month for a period of 15 days. I can give  approximate dates of intended travel and return but could not book tickets because of uncertainty of visa being obtained in time. I can produce a ticket when visa is confirmed.

Comment: You can get a fully refundable ticket if you are worried about not getting the visa and loosing the money you spent on buying the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

In a Schengen visa application - you don't apply for a specific period, you apply for a specific itinerary and if you want single, dual or multiple entries.

Of all the Schengen documentation I have seen, it never mentions a *ticket*, but plenty of places mention a *reservation*; which makes sense as you may not be granted the visa.

Typical requirements for Schengen (tourist) visa:

1. Itinerary
2. Proof of accommodation (like a hotel reservation for the dates)
3. Proof of funds to cover your trip
4. Proof of travel insurance
5. Proof of family ties/home ties

Normal requirements - passport current for 6 months past your travel dates, a passport sized photo on a white background, copy of your passport, copy of your residency permit (if you are a permanent resident in the country you are applying).